# Referencing an Assembly in the Application Path

Tags: ironpython, system.data.sqlite, assembly-reference-path

I am trying to reference [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) which is located in the application path so that I can package it with the application. I have tried several different ways including:

```
#1
clr.AddReferenceToFile("System.Data.SQLite.DLL")

#2
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("C:\\Path\\To\\System.Data.SQLite.DLL")

#3
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
clr.AddReferenceToFile("System.Data.SQLite.DLL")
```

Each time it will either give me an error: "Could not load assembly System.Data.SQLite" or that it can't find the specified file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we generally add references at work is the following:

```
import sys
import clr
# forward slashes work fine here and don't need to be escaped
sys.path.append('c:/path/to/directory/containing/dll')
clr.AddReference('System.Data.SQLite') # note lack of .dll
```

Comment: Ill try that out and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that sqlite3.dll is in your path, or that you are using the version of the S.D.SQLite that has the sqlite3.dll embedded in it.